# AJAX success call taking only one value from JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I am passing an array using json_encode from PHP file to $.ajax call. When I check the output of PHP it shows that values are being passed correctly but in ajax call it accepts only the first key-value and rest becomes either 0 or null. Please help. Here is my code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<label class="control-label">Date Range</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group input-large date-picker input-daterange" data-date="10/11/2012" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input id="frmdate" type="text" class="form-control" name="from">
<span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
<input id="todate" type="text" class="form-control" name="to"> </div>
<button type="button" onClick="get_val();" class="btn grey-mint">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="tile double-down">
<div class="tile-body">
<div id="tot_whouse"> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="tile-object">                                      
<div style="text-align: center;">Total Whouses </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tile double-down">
<div class="tile-body">
<div id="vis_whouse"> </div>
</div>
<div class="tile-object">                                               
<div style="text-align: center;">Whouse Visited </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tile double">
<div class="tile-body">
<div id="ad_dfs"> </div>
</div>
<div class="tile-object">
<div class="name"> % Whouse having adequate Stock </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$indi = array();
$dtfrom = $_REQUEST['dtfrm']; // From Date
$dtto = $_REQUEST['dateto']; // To Date

//Total Whouse
$sql = "SELECT count(ID) FROM `W_Mast` WHERE S_I=3";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$totwe=$row[0];
$indi['tot_whouse']=$totwe;

// Whouse Visited
$sql = "SELECT count(wm.ID) FROM `WHouseMonitor` wm INNER JOIN W_Mast w on wm.WhouseID=w.WHouse_ID WHERE w.S_I=3 and wm.visit_date BETWEEN $dtfrom and $dtto";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$w_visited = $row[0]; //Will be used as Denominator in next query result
$indi['vis_whouse']=$w_visited;

//Whouse have stock
$sql = "SELECT count(wm.ID) FROM `WHouseMonitor` wm INNER JOIN W_Mast w on wm.WhouseID=w.WHouse_ID WHERE w.S_I=3 and wm.dfs_open>=dfs_suppquar and wm.visit_date BETWEEN $dtfrom and $dtto";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$w_adeqdfs= round((($row[0]/$w_visited)*100),1);
$indi['adeq_dfs']=strval($w_adeqdfs);

echo json_encode($indi);
```

The result of this PHP when checked by passing parameters through url-

```
https://website.com/whouse.php?dtfrm="2019-01-01"&dateto="2040-12-31"
```

> {"tot_whouse":"210","vis_whouse":"8","adeq_dfs":"100"}

**Javascript with $.ajax script:**

```
<script>
var dtfrom;
var dtto;
function get_val()
{
dtfrom = document.getElementById("frmdate").value;
dtto = document.getElementById("todate").value;
if(dtfrom==""){
dtfrom ="2019-01-01";
}
if(dtto==""){
dtto ="2040-12-31";
}
$.ajax({
  url: "whouse.php",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    dtfrm: dtfrom,
    dateto: dtto
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $("#tot_whouse").html(response['tot_whouse']);
    $("#vis_whouse").html(response['vis_whouse']);
    $("#ad_dfs").html(response['adeq_dfs'] + '%');
  },
  error: function(e, ts, et) {
    alert(ts);
    alert(et);
  }
});
}
</script>
```

$.ajax response variable is receiving the following values:

> {"tot_whouse":"210","vis_whouse":"0","adeq_dfs":"NAN"}

Any ideas why it is not taking values of **"vis_whouse"** and **"adeq_dfs"**.

Thank You!

Comment: Assuming that response is being received just as you've shown, then in theory there's nothing wrong with your code - demo https://jsfiddle.net/e738h9rg/ . Maybe you've got the name of your selectors wrong or something? We can't see the target HTML. Try logging those individual values to the console within your "success", and see if it prints them. Then you'll know if it's the data or the selector which is at fault.

Comment: Are `vis_whouse` and `ad_dfs` are input box or div?

Comment: Hi @ADyson , name of the selectors are correct and the values received by **response** has been printed in their respective divs. I have logged the values in console and here is the result:
`{tot_whouse: "210", vis_whouse: "0", adeq_dfs: "NAN"}`
adeq_dfs: "NAN"
tot_whouse: "210"
vis_whouse: "0"

Comment: @Swati vis_whouse and ad_dfs are divs.

Comment: "name of the selectors are correct and the values received by response has been printed in their respective divs" ... ok so why did you say "in ajax call it accepts only the first key-value and rest becomes either 0 or null" ... "it is not taking values of "vis_whouse" and "adeq_dfs"...this sounds like the values are not being output into your page. The values are there - the last one is "NaN", not the same as `null`. If they're not the values you expected, that's a different problem. You could have made that a lot clearer, people have been wasting their time on the wrong issue.

Comment: So actually your AJAX code is probably not relevant here, the issue is the results of your PHP code, and by extension, the results of your queries. So you need to debug those. We don't know what date input values you sent - can you give an example of those, and then some relevant sample data from the database table, and then the result you **expected** from your queries, based on that data? Because we cannot see any of that.

Comment: But if I had to guess I'd say maybe the queries are going wrong because 1) the dates are not in a format SQL can understand, 2) the queries are not properly prepared and parameterised to deal with the input (and thus might generate invalid values or even syntax errors, as well as being prone to SQL injection attacks), 3) the values don't match anything in your database, or 4) some combination of the three options above.

Comment: in the case of `adeq_dfs` it's also possible that your `round` function is not producing the correct result, but again the root cause of that is likely to be that the output from the database is not what you were expecting. Hence why we need sample input data, sample database data, and expected results.

Comment: As a general warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: @Dyson Thanks for looking into this matter seriously. I value the time invested by other coders to solve my problem. That is the reason why I have posted the results from my PHP script. Values I am getting from my SQL queries are correct. Let me again show the result of my PHP  and AJAX. PHP output is {"tot_whouse":"210","vis_whouse":"8","adeq_dfs":"100"} and AJAX response output is {"tot_whouse":"210","vis_whouse":"0","adeq_dfs":"NAN"}. You can clearly see that response has only picked "tot_whouse" value. "vis_whouse" has become 0 and "adeq_dfs" has become "NAN". That is the issue!

Comment: @Bunts sorry but that isn't possible. If PHP outputs something when it's called via AJAX, then AJAX will receive that exact response from PHP - JSON is just text, the values within it do not get transformed between server and client. Please be clearer about how exactly you are obtaining these different results. Are you calling the PHP in a different way to get the first result? And how are you seeing the AJAX response output exactly? Again you didn't explain the precise source. Is it in the console? Or in your Network tool, or what? Screenshots might help, if you can't articulate it.

Comment: @Dyson I have found the problem! As you have correctly mentioned, the problem was indeed with the PHP. Dates should have been passed as a string value. I was getting the PHP output by passing the dates in the url in double codes. I have converted the dates received from AJAX to string and it worked! Thanks for your tips regarding PHP/mysqli which I will surely follow. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you solved it. So basically a typo really?

Comment: @Dyson Not typo actually. The dates should have been passed as a string with double/single quotes :)

Comment: Well that is trivial enough to count as a typo I think. But of course it would never have been a problem to begin with if your queries were correctly parameterised - so I suggest that should be the next thing you sort out :-)

Comment: Sure, I still have to work a lot to improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem! Dates being passed to PHP should be in string format. So what I did is I have converted the dates into the string in my SQL queries and now my AJAX is receiving correct responses.

Earlier my sql query was:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(wm.ID) FROM `WHouseMonitor` wm INNER JOIN W_Mast w on wm.WhouseID=w.WHouse_ID WHERE w.S_I=3 and wm.visit_date BETWEEN $dtfrom and $dtto";
```

which I have now changed to:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(wm.ID) FROM `WHouseMonitor` wm INNER JOIN W_Mast w on wm.WhouseID=w.WHouse_ID WHERE w.S_I=3 and wm.visit_date BETWEEN '".$dtfrom."' and '".$dtto."'";
```

Thanks everyone for helping!